# Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Tags: php, laravel-7

So i got error when uploading image on my web form and here is the code :

```
public function newStoreBlog(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'category' => ['required'],
            'image' => ['required'],
            'description' => ['required','string'],
        ]);

        $photoFile = $request->file('image');
        Storage::putFileAs('public/photos',$photoFile, $photoFile->getClientOriginalName());

        Article::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $request->input('category')->id,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'image' => $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName(),
            'description' => $request->description,
        ]);
```

here is my route on web.php

```
Route::post('/myblog/new/store', 'HomeController@newStoreBlog');
```

and this is my blade form

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Photo') }}</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="image" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}" required autocomplete="image" autofocus>
                    @error('image')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
```

the error showing that the image is null, how can i solve it?

Comment: Does your form have the mandatory `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: it said the category_id cannot be read from the program

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller should like this.

```
public function newStoreBlog(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'category' => ['required'],
            'image' => ['required'],
            'description' => ['required','string'],
        ]);

        $fileName = null;
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $photoFile = $request->file('image');
            $fileName = $photoFile->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::putFileAs('public/photos',$photoFile, $fileName);
        }
 
        Article::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
            'title' => $request->title,
            'image' => $fileName,
            'description' => $request->description,
        ]);
```